# On a number line, A is at -2 and B is at 4. What is the coordinate of C, which is 2/3 of the way from A to B

Tags: geometry

On a number line, $A$ is at $-2$ and $B$ is at $4$. What is the coordinate of $C$, which is $2/3$ of the way from $A$ to $B$?

I was studying segment bisectors and midpoints so the problems would go something like this: $AB = BC$ because they are congruent which means you can solve for $x$. However with this problem I do not understand how to incorporate the fraction into the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A $ and $B$ are $4-(-2)=6$ units apart.

> C is at a distance of $(2/3)\times 6=4$  from A . So C is at $-2+4=2$

Comment: Where did the 6 come from?

Comment: 6 units is the distance between A and B $4-(-2)=6$

Comment: Ok so then what would C be equal to?

Comment: Click on the spoiler and you will know.

Answer (score 1):

$$AC = 2/3 \cdot AB = 2/3 \cdot (4--2) \to AC = 4, C = -2 + 4 = 2$$

Answer (score 1):

The distance between two points is $|x_a - x_b|$. Note that it doesn't matter who you call A and B in this case. So multiply that number by 2/3. Since A is to the left of B, you have to add this number as positive. If you wanted to go from B to A, you'd have to add the same number but as a negative number.

More formally, the vector that goes from A to B is $x_b - x_a$. In this case, the first position is the position of the end of the vector, while the second one is the position where you started. So to go from A to B you'd have to do $x_a + (x_b-x_a)$. Do that and you'll realize that what you have is $x_b$ (the position of B in the real plane). Now, to go 2/3 from A to B means to start at A and add 2/3 of the vector that goes from A to B. So that'd be $x_a + \frac{2(x_b-x_a)}{3}$